# Firestore: Couldn't Serialize object of type 'ArrayUnionTransform'

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to updates elements in an array using the Firestore docs example:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var washingtonRef = firestore.collection('cities').doc('DC');

var arrUnion = washingtonRef.update({
  regions: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('greater_virginia')
});
```

However when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an 
alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an 
optional precondition. Argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Document. 
Couldn't serialize object of type "ArrayUnionTransform" (found in field 
regions). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom 
prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).
```

Comment: Do you mean you are using the exact same code or you are using this code as an example for your own code? The code in the docs works as expected.

Comment: @jal_a I'm using the exact same code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct SDK.

The reason this was not working was because my reference to `firestore.collection('cities').doc('DC');` was actually coming from here:

```
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore'); // this is the wrong SDK.

const firestore = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'my-project'
  keyFilename: fbKeyFile
});
```

As it states on the [README.md](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore#readme) this is wrong:

> Applications that use Google's Server SDKs should not be used in end-user environments, such as on phones or on publicly hosted websites. If you are developing a Web or Node.js application that accesses Cloud Firestore on behalf of end users, use the firebase Client SDK.

Therefor to get it working I simple switched the following:

```
firestore.collection('cities').doc('DC');
// to
FirebaseAdmin.firestore().collection('cities').doc('DC');
```